# With every Chumra comes a Kula

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-bavli, stringency-chumrah, leniencies

Where in Shas  can I find the statement that with every chumra one takes on, he is in essence going to be taking a on a kula somewhere else? I'm pretty sure it's in Beitza somewhere...

Answer (score 7):

The gemara does not say that **every** stringency leads to a leniency, but **sometimes** it does, and thus the gemara may challenge that a certain stringency is a חומרא דאתי לידי קולא - a stringency which leads to a leniency, for example in [Pesachim 48b](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=pesachim&daf=48b), [Yevamos 30b](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=yevamos&daf=30b&go=Go), [Bava Kama 11a](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=bava_kama&daf=11a&go=Go) and [Niddah 24b](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=nidah&daf=24b&go=Go).

Comment: How do you know it never says that?

Comment: @DoubleAA wouldn't finding any chumra not challenged thusly be how one would know?  If that is a challenge to a chumra, and every chumra leads to a kula, then it would be a challenge to every chumra.

Comment: it doesnt have to be a challenge to be a rule so your sylogism fails @yez

Comment: @DoubleAA Any suggestion for why it would be a bothersome point for a chumra to lead to a kula some days but not others?

Comment: @YEZ It's not a matter of what day it is. It matters how big the kula is. I don't know where I implied that its temporally linked.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing I could find is this, on 16a:

> ואמר רב תחלת הוראה דהאי צורבא מרבנן לקלקולא אי אמרת בשלמא לקולא קאמר היינו קלקולא אלא אי אמרת לחומרא מאי קלקולא איכא כיון דמקלקלי בה רבים
>   היינו קלקולא
>   (in the context of a chumra) Rav Tachlis says: This young rabbi's ruling is problematic. The gemara asks "if it were unnecessarily lenient I would understand why that's a problem, but it's stringent, so what could go wrong? [Answer] Because people will violate it (due to its stringency) that is a problem in and of itself. (my translation)